# Getting a count of lines while also processing the lines using lambdas

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-11

I am trying to get a count of lines that have been processed by a lambda iterating over lines in a BufferedReader.

Is there a way to get a count without writing the 2nd lambda to get just the line count?

```
        final BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

        inReader.lines().forEach(line -> {
            
            // do something with the line
         });
```

Can I get a count also in the above code block? I am using Java 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong();
lines.stream().forEach(line -> {
    count.getAndIncrement();
    // do something with line;
});
```

Comment: Correct. Streams have two types of functions:terminal and not terminal. Non-terminal operations return a stream and terminal returns something else. forEach is terminal and you can't call count in the result, because it's not a stream. In other hand peek is a non terminal operation doest he same - apply a consumer to the stream - but breturns the same steam received as input so now you can call count() to the result.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to count in your lamba. Sure, you can do that. Just initialize a `count` variable before executing the `forEach` and increase the `count` in your lambda block. Like this:

```
final BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

// fixed the long by this
final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
inReader.lines().forEach(line -> {
  counter.incrementAndGet();
  // do something with the line
});
// here you can do something with the count variable, like printing it out
System.out.printf("count=%d%n", counter.get());
```

The `forEach` method comes from `Iterable`. It is definiately not the way I would choose to process the reader. I would do something like this:

```
try (BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"))) {
  Stream<String> lines = inReader.lines();
  
  long i = lines.peek(line -> {
        
        // do something with the line
     }).count();
  
  System.out.printf("count=%d%n", i);
```

}

PS: Didn't really test this, so correct me if I did a mistake.